# how to get active REPL block in PyScript and copy whatever code written in it?

Tags: python, react-typescript, pyscript, pyodide

I have multiple code blocks in pyscript repl which were created dynamically on button click. I want to know which code block is active. I know library adds `cm-activeLine` class  when line is active but that changes when I click some other button to get the class..
I want to change order of code blocks on button click. what I am thinking is I will copy all code inside editor and Swap it with other code block but I dont know how to get the code inside editor. library has no documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My scenario was to add new **repl tag** on a button click inside a **div** as child and then determine which `repl` tag is active to perform further operations.
The workaround I used was to enclose all of `<py-repl />` tags inside `<div />` and added an event listener `onClick` on the div. Inside event I am searching for div with `cm-focused` class.

```
const selectActiveCodeBlock = useCallback(() => {
 let div: any = document.querySelector("div.cm-focused");
  if (!div) {
   selectedCodeBlock.current = null;
   return;
  }

  selectedCodeBlock.current = div.closest("py-repl");
 }, []);
```

Now I have reference of active `repl` in `selectedCodeBlock` if it was clicked else it will be `null`.

To get the code written inside `repl` as a string:

`let code = selectedCodeBlock.current.editor.state.doc.toString();`